# Getting JS to trigger fullscreen and audio to play

Tags: javascript, html, dom, media

I am trying to set this up so that when you scroll down, this song starts to play and when you click anywhere on the page it enters fullscreen. It seems I can only have the click either allow audio to start playing or to enter fullscreen but I can't have both.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    

</head>
<body onscroll="playSong()">
    <div class="front" onclick="openFullscreen">
        <button onclick="openFullscreen">open</button>
    <p>this is it ladies, you need to do the click</p>
</div>
    <img src="final_comp.gif" id="gif">
    <audio  id="audio">
        <source src="LTYT.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
        <script>
/* Get the documentElement (<html>) to display the page in fullscreen */
var elem = document.documentElement;

/* View in fullscreen */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>
<script>
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

    function playSong() {
        audio.play();
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The only way I could get it to open in full screen was by adding this `window.onclick = function () {openFullscreen() };` but it would through up errors in the console. I added another one `window.onscroll = function () {playSong() };` and now everything works!